# Create an executable that is an alias for another command

Tags: command-line, bash, python, youtube, alias

I've downloaded Open Video Downloader which is a gui to youtube-dl (which is kinda dead)
I've replaced it with `yt-dlp` (youtube-dl fork which is working)

My problem is that **`yt-dlp` needs python 3.7+ to work**.
When OpenVideoDownloader spawns `/home/myuser/.youtube-dl-gui/yt-dlp-unix`, I get an error regarding this, because I've set Python 2.7 as default in my Ubuntu 20.04

I've installed python3.9 and running this on bash works:

```
/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/myuser/.youtube-dl-gui/yt-dlp-unix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceiyvKwpRRo*
```

So, how could I replace `/home/myuser/.youtube-dl-gui/yt-dlp-unix` with another **executable/batch/alias** that really calls `/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/myuser/.youtube-dl-gui/yt-dlp-unix` (with all the parameters given) so OpenVideoDownloader can spawn it and work fine?

**All this because I've read if I set python3.9 as default I may break my Ubuntu install, etc.**

Thanks for any idea

Comment: Can't you just edit `/home/myuser/.youtube-dl-gui/yt-dlp-unix` and change `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python3.9`?

Comment: https://www.videohelp.com/software/Open-Video-Downloader
for linux. I use youtube-dl all the time. it works fine for me. version 2021.12.17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### Script

Create a script in your path with these contents: (called `ytdl` in this example)

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/myuser/.youtube-dl-gui/yt-dlp-unix "$@"
```

`"$@"` means all parameters will be passed on.

If you want to add a fixed parameter, include it in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/myuser/.youtube-dl-gui/yt-dlp-unix --ffmpeg-location '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' "$@"
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x ./ytdl
```

###### Alias

You can achieve the same thing by just creating an alias:

```
alias ytdl="/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/myuser/.youtube-dl-gui/yt-dlp-unix --ffmpeg-location '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'"
```

Arguments are automatically passed to an alias, so you just have to source the file containing the alias (for instance `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`).

Now running `ytdl` will do what you want.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks a lot !